# How to generate a logfile using xcopy with task Scheduler - no bat file

Tags: automation, updates, windows-task-scheduler, xcopy, logfiles

I'm updating some files every day with task scheduler using xcopy. My syntax is

```
 xcopy "\\networkFolder...\" "c:\folder" /D /Y /E /I > c:\users\name\desktop\logfolder\log.txt
```

It works perfectly in cmd line but when I take It to task Scheduler nothing happens.

On task shceduler, it also works perfectly without the path for the log 
`> c:\users\name\desktop\logfolder\log.txt` copies only the missing or updated files, but I'd like to be reported on the changes. I can't use a .bat file because there's accents on the path

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I switched to robocopy with /XO and /LOG+ parameters and worked ok. 
Hate the report format, tho.
Thanks everybody